# Alexa Skill offline

Tags: echo, alexa-skills-kit

Does anyone here have experience building an Alexa Skill that can be accessed if the device is not online? Need something for a demo and trying to understand the possibilities.

I have built something on SaySpring, but it just does not quite have the "wow" effect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use to have the Lambda function on AWS, than it will not working in the offline mode.
**But:**

There is the possibility to create a own Lambda Backend at a url you want using https. Thats quite difficult and I never tried it correctly before. Have a closer to it [here](https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-a-web-service.html).

It would be great, if you can share your experience, because I'm looking forward to a individual solution like that.